# I want to share links to documents on SharePoint Online which open directly in the Office 365 web apps

Tags: sharepoint-online

I want to share links to documents on SharePoint Online which open directly in the Office 365 web apps. If I use a link to the file like `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/site/folder/word.doc` IE will open it in the Word web app just fine, but Chrome prompts to download it instead.
Is there any way to add a suffix to the URL which will trigger other browsers than IE to open it in the respective web app?

I am aware that when I generate a permanent link to a document in SharePoint in the form of `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/site/_layouts/15/DocIdRedir.aspx?ID=xxxx-1234567890-123` it will work also in Chrome. The thing is that I want the URL to be meaningful, so the recipient will be able to tell in which path/folder the document is located.

Answer (score 1):

I think, it is not SharePoint specific but its more related to browser. Chrome will always download the file.

when the file is downloaded click on the "v" icon at the right hand end of its button on the downloads bar.
select "always open this file type" and then open it.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/otaZ-hRtmOY

Comment: That doesn't really help, as we want to avoid people downloading the file and saving it locally. I thought maybe there is a way to add a suffix to the URL like &action=edit or the like to force it to open in the web app.

Answer (score 1):

Realise this was posted a year ago, but for the author / anyone else interested...

Yes, you can do this by adding `?web=1` to the end.

e.g. `https://xxx.sharepoint.com/teams/site/folder/word.doc?web=1`

Thanks,
Martin